# Combinatorics with Bashy

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, contest-math, gcd-and-lcm

We call a set of positive integer good, if the greatest common divisor of all of the elements in this set is $1$.
$a_n$ is the number of good subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$. Find all integer $n \ge 2019$, such that, $\forall \> 0<k<n, k \in Z$, $\frac{a_{n+k}}{a_n} < \frac{a_n}{a_{n-k}}$

Is there a quick solution to this problem?

What I thought: $2^n-1= \sum_{d=1}^{n}{a_{[\frac{n}{d}]}}$a

2019 NGC Girls MO

Comment: "2019 NGC Girls MO"?

Comment: @Mnifldz NGC stands for 守夜杯
It was held on a Chinese social media group chat.
Its major purpose is to mitigate the sorrow of these who are not eligible to participate in CGMO because of their biological identities, namely, boys.

Comment: Are you sure about your claim for $n = 3$?

Comment: @CalvinLin See if you understand the statement now